# Laravel - Installing packages that were installed with composer on live server

Tags: php, server, composer-php, namecheap

I have a laravel project on **namecheap** shared server, I have set up everything and it is working there. But after that, I have added locally on my machine to the project `imagecache intervention` package with composer. I don't know how to install it on the server though, I have tried with running composer commands through ssh:

```
php composer require intervention/imagecache
```

But I got an error:

> Could not open input file: composer

Since, their support told me that they actually have composer uploaded in the folder `public_html` and not where my project is and that is `public_html/myProject` if that is the problem. Since I have no idea, how the composer is installed and setup there, I wonder how can I install this package. I have also tried by just uploading the whole directory of the package from my local vendor folder in the project to the production server, but that didn't work either, images were still not visible when I was using `imagecache` route. How can I fix that?

Comment: Seems like you haven't installed `composer` itself on the server

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/download/ . Install it in the same path as your composer.json if you can't install it in a folder in your `path` (e.g. /usr/bin)

Comment: their support service told me they have installed the composer but they have installed it in the folder public_html, is that the composer.phar file and can I just move it then to my project folder?

Answer (score 2):

Run this: `php -c php.ini composer.phar install`

First You have to create php.ini file with this info.

```
max_execution_time = 300 
max_input_time = 300 
memory_limit = 512M 
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar 
detect_unicode = Off
```

Comment: php -c php.ini composer.phar install  without /upd it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh then you can create a folder where ever you wan't.
It is better if you put it in the same level that your public folder and then install composer inside this folder:

with curl

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

if you don't have curl or the server has restrictions you can use:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

or you can "Manual Download" the composer.phar and upload it trough ftp

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Then you need to give execution rights to the composer.phar file and you

```
chmod a+x composer.phar
```

can also create an alias to run composer from your public folder

```
alias composer="path/to/composer/composer.phar"
```

This alias will work until you close your console.  In some shared servers you will see a file call: .bashrc where you can put the alias

Comment: It's worth noting that most of this is optional and for convenience. All you need at minimum is a copy of composer.phar somewhere on the server that you have read permission for, and then you can run `php path/to/composer.phar install`